Where did I go wrong in this splitted curve Integral problem
Find the area between the curve $y = 2x^3 - x^2 - 1$ and the $x-$axis, in range limitation $-2 \le x \le 2$ i.e., $[-2, 2]$.
$$\int_{-2}^{2} \left(2x^3 - x^2 - 1\right) \, dx$$
\begin{align}\text{Area}&=\int_{-2}^{2} \mid 2x^2 - x^2 - 1 \mid \, dx\\&=\int_{-2}^{-1} (2x^2 - x^2 - 1)  \, dx+ \int_{-1}^{1} ( 2x^2 - x^2 - 1)  \, dx+ \int_{1}^{2}  (2x^2 - x^2 - 1 ) \, dx 
\end{align}
Integrating
$$ \left[\frac{2x^4}{4} - \frac{x^3}{3} - x\right]_{-2}^{-1} + \left[\frac{2x^4}{4} - \frac{x^3}{3} - x\right]_{-1}^{1} + \left[\frac{2x^4}{4} - \frac{x^3}{3} - x\right]_{1}^{2}$$
Applying
$$\left( F(-1) - F(-2) \right) + \left(F(1) - F(-1)\right) + \left( F(2) - F(1) \right)= -\frac{65}{6} + (-\frac{8}{3}) + \frac{3}{2}$$
My answer was wrong, according to the back of the book the correct solution is: $$\color{red}{\frac{53}{3}}$$.

The absolute value of $2x^{3}-x^{2}-1$ when $-2\leq x\leq 1$ is $-\left(2x^{3}-x^{2}-1\right)=-2x^{3}+x^{2}+1$. Your area should be $$A=\int\limits_{-2}^{1}\left(-2x^{3}+x^{2}+1\right)dx+\int\limits_{1}^{2}\left(2x^{3}-x^{2}-1\right)dx$$ instead.

Why $\approx$ and not $=$?

$2x^3 - x^2 - 1=(x-1)(2x^2 + x + 1)=0$
there is only one x-intercept that is $x=1$ and
since $2x^3 - x^2 - 1 < 0$ when $x<1$, $2x^3 - x^2 - 1 \geq 0$ when $x\geq1$
Area $ = \int_{-2}^{2} \mid 2x^3 - x^2 - 1 \mid \, dx $
$ = \int_{-2}^{1}  (-2x^3 + x^2 + 1 ) \, dx + \int_{1}^{2}  (2x^3 - x^2 - 1 ) \, dx $
$= \left[\frac{-x^4}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + x\right]_{-2}^{1} + \left[\frac{x^4}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} - x\right]_{1}^{2} =  \frac{81}{6} + \frac{25}{6} = \frac{53}{3} $
